# problem about expression “period of facility”

Tags: phrase-meaning

> Whatever the world to come, the Western peoples will play in it the part of the Graeculi in the Roman Empire. Sought out and despised by the new conqueror, they will have, in order to impress him, only the jugglery of their intelligence or the luster of their past. The art of surviving oneself—they are already distinguished in that. Symptoms of exhaustion are everywhere: Germany has given her measure in music: what leads us to believe that she will excel in it again? She has used up the resources of her profundity, as France those of her elegance. Both—and with them, this entire corner of the world—are on the verge of bankruptcy, the most glamorous since antiquity. Then will come the liquidation: a prospect which is not a negligible one, a respite whose duration cannot be estimated, a **period of facility** in which each man, before the deliverance finally at hand, will be happy to have behind him the throes of hope and expectation.

This is the quote from Emil Cioran's "The Temptation to  Exist", my problem is how to understand this expression "period of facility" in this sentence, and I've got a legal term "facility period" [link](https://definedterm.com/facility_period), but i dont know if this meaning is appropriate for this sentence, and if it is, how can i understand this expression inside the text?

Comment: I believe it's talking about the unknown of death in some way, but it's impossible to be more specific without additional context.

Comment: more context added, hope it will help

Comment: I think you need to look into the definitions of [*facility*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/facility) itself. The context isn't real clear to me, but I would go with "2. a ready ability; skill; dexterity; fluency", basically those thing we do on a normal day-to-day basis; in this example for some period of time.

Comment: @user3169 so u mean it simply means "some period of time"?

Comment: Amazing. Now, it obviously has nothing to do with death at all . . . ;)

Comment: Maybe it's a typo for "period of **felicity**. Probably translated from French: une période de felicité"

Answer (score -1):

In your excerpt, the phrase

> **period of facility**

means ***a period of time to allow something*** (a period of time to *facilitate* something).  In your example, the period of time specifically allows the shedding of

> **hope and expectation**

The author is basically saying that before one dies

> **before the deliverance finally at hand**

one goes through a period of losing hope and expectation, *a reasons to live*, and then lets go.  The amount of time ti takes for this penultimate step is unknown.